# Why does my getter,setter not working in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to check my password`s length before assigning value to the password. If value's length is less than 3 it has to throw an error. But it is not returning anything. Why?

I have a Department class and ITDepartment subclass.

```
class Department {
    static currentYear = 2022
    departmentName:string
    empNum:number
    employees :string[] = []
    constructor(public name:string,nums:number, 
        employees:string[]){
        this.departmentName =name
        this.empNum = nums
        this.employees = employees
    }


}

class ITDepartment extends Department {
orginizingDate : number
 private password :number

 public get pass (){
    return this.password
 }


 public set pass (value:number){
    if(value.toString().length < 3){
        throw new Error ('The password is not safe ')
    }
     this.password = value
 }

constructor(empNum:number,employees:string[],orginizingDate :number,password:number){
    super("IT",empNum,employees)
    this.orginizingDate = orginizingDate
    this.password = password
}
printInfo(){
    console.log("The Department " + this.departmentName  +" has " + this.empNum +" employers and orginized in " +this.orginizingDate)
}

addEmployee(employee: string): void {
    if(employee === "Adam"){
        return
    }
    this.employees.push(employee)
}
}   

let it = new ITDepartment(52,[],2000,22)
```

Comment: What is `Department`?  Please try to provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue if I paste it into a standalone IDE.   Right now my IDE doesn't even begin to know what you're doing here.

Comment: I don't seem to reproduce any problems - https://tsplay.dev/WoABMN

Comment: Your constructor doesn't use the setter but directly assigns to `.password`

Comment: @jcalz Department is my main class. I edited the questionş

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this.password = password` won't go through the setter named `pass`. Furthermore, you aren't actually comparing the length, but the value itself.

Comment: Without this.password = password  it is showing  **Property 'password' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor** error

Comment: That error is a TS limitation (see [ms/TS#21132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21132)) and can be worked around in various ways, such as `declare`-ing the property as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/mq3Aqw).